# SSRS - Open link to PDF with # in file name in new window

Tags: reporting-services

I'm writing a report that will allow the user to type in an order number and display a list of all the documents that have been attached to it in our MRP system. It's a MSSQL database. The problem I'm running into is that users are using a hashtag (#) in the file name. So a file might be "PO# 12345.PDF" for example. If the file were named "PO 12345.PDF" the link works as expected.

The action link is:
`="javascript:void( window.open('" & Fields!LINK.Value & "', 'blank','scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, width=780, height=1040'))"`

I've even tried converting the value in the SQL script instead and when I hover over the rendered link in the report it has %23 instead of the # but, when I click the link it changes back to a #. Anyone have a way to handle this? Below is the SQL I'm using.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT          PURCHASE_ORDER.ID, 
        DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.DOCUMENT_ID, 
        [DOCUMENT].DOC_FILE_PATH, 
        DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.CREATE_DATE, 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT([DOCUMENT].DOC_FILE_PATH, '/', DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.DOCUMENT_ID), 'V:\', 'http://mac-file01.mac.local/vis/'), '#', '%23') AS LINK, 
        [DOCUMENT].DESCRIPTION, 
        VENDOR.NAME, 
        DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.SOURCE_TYPE
FROM            PURCHASE_ORDER INNER JOIN
                         DOCUMENT_REFERENCE ON PURCHASE_ORDER.ID = DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.ID INNER JOIN
                         [DOCUMENT] ON DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.DOCUMENT_ID = [DOCUMENT].ID INNER JOIN
                         VENDOR ON PURCHASE_ORDER.VENDOR_ID = VENDOR.ID
WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER.ID = @JobNum AND PURCHASE_ORDER.ID = DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.ID AND
DOCUMENT_REFERENCE.SOURCE_TYPE = 'R'
```

Comment: I tested this by selecting the static value `https://example.com/pdfs/PO%23 12345.PDF` and it worked for me. It just renders like this `<a tabindex="5" href="http://example.com/pdfs/PO%23%2012345.PDF" target="_top"><div>My cool hyperlink</div></a>`. What does your HTML output look like? Also, maybe it’s a browser thing? I tested Firefox and Edge.

Comment: The rendered link in the report page looks like this:
`<a tabindex="4" href="javascript:void(%20window.open('http://xxxxx.xxx.local/vis/scans%20for%20visual%202022/PO%23%2060556-SG02124%20Demag(2).pdf',%20'blank','scrollbars=yes,%20toolbar=no,%20width=780,%20height=1040'))" style="" class="A1337cceb968a46219864f8f26aee4ff574a" target="_top"><div style="width:16.49mm;min-width: 16.49mm;">CLICK ME</div></a>`

Comment: but when I click that link in Edge it changes to `http://xxxxx.xxx.local/vis/scans%20for%20visual%202022/PO#%2060556-SG02124%20Demag(2).pdf`